# Rescuing eclipse from bad workspace/project data

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

I would like to take a step backwards opening eclipse without it automatically opening the source files which were last open, nor the projects which were last loaded, I have reason to believe this might clear it all up.

Motivation being that as of a forced quit of eclipse, after it had gone stuck after some project changes, my eclipse Luna is no longer able to start without getting hung up again.

How may I accomplish that?

It's important to me not to lose my settings such as syntax highlighting and stuff, while performing the salvation... and whereas I am pretty certain I could locate my workspace directory on disk, would be nice finding where does eclipse keep the pointer to it, just to make sure I'll be tinkering with the right workspace, if needed..

I guess I could call it "starting eclipse in safe mode" :)

Comment: all your settings are in ${workspace}/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings 
Before doing anything, i would backup that folder so you can rollback in case things go bad. hard to tell what to look at without knowing more about your error

Comment: Luckily I could trace back what makes scala compilation stuck, reverting the relevant source file and eclipse is back to life now. Good to know the procedure for "safe mode" though :)